# what URL should I add in callback url if I have a cluster of nodes in HA active active wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, high-availability

I am working on HA (high availability) mode of wso2 api manager with two nodes. I was able to run this nodes in dependability with no issues , but now when I have added the proxy port and host name for my load balancer ... I am getting callback issues what should i do here doc of wso2 does not say anything about callbacks with this HA cluster

Comment: Have you checked https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/#troubleshooting-registered-callback-does-not-match-with-the-provided-url-error ?